# Migration doesn't apply on all foreign keys the ON CASCADE DELETE behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, table-relationships

I am using Entity Framework Core 5 and I am testing the table relationships.
Using these 2 classes as entities

```
public class Absenta
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataAbsemta { get; set; }
    public bool Motivata { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int TrainingID { get; set; }
    public Training Training { get; set; }
}

public class Training
{
    public int TrainingID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Training")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Clasa")]
    public string NumeClasa { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Sala")]
    public string NumeSala { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data incepere : ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataInceput { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data sfarsit  : ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataSfarsit { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Absenta> absente { get; set; }
}
```

This is the generated query :

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Absente] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Absente_AspNetUsers_UserID] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Absente_Traininguri_TrainingID] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([TrainingID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Traininguri] ([TrainingID]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Migration works perfectly, creating the tables and foreign keys, but for the `UserID` foreign key it does not apply `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior by default.

Is there a way I can set it as default from the class? I am trying to avoid setting it manually for every table.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.
All you have to do is use the `[Required]` data annotation :

```
[Required]
public string UserID { get; set; }

public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```